# Como comparar el resultado de una variable sea igual al nombre de una columna

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, variables

Hola es mi primer post quisiera saber como puedo comparar el resultado de una variable con un titulo de una columna en SQL SERVER

SI EL VALOR DE @MES ES OCTUBRE ACTUALICE LA COLUMNA OCTUBRE SI ES NOVIEMBRE ACTUALICE NOVIEMBRE Y ASÍ:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DECLARE @MES VARCHAR (MAX)
SET @MES = (SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,'20211001'))
PRINT @MES 

UPDATE #ACUMULADO_INS SET @MES = INCENTIVO ---HARDCODE
FROM #ACUMULADO_INS AS A INNER JOIN #INSTITUCIONAL AS I ON A.RUTA= I.RUTA AND A.PRODUCTO = I.PRODUCTO
```

Comment: Investiga sobre sql dinamico

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. No veo nada claro, lo que intentas. ¿Que tiene que ver el valor de una variable con el título de una columna? La definición de una tabla no va a cambiar por que tengas una u otra columna. Si estás intentando actualizar los valores de la columna OCTUBRE, tendrías que hacer algo en el `where`, pero quizá si expones lo que estás intentando hacer, ya que de la imagen, te podamos ayudar a montar, lo que parece un pivot dinámico. Y eliminar quizas las innecesarias posibles tablas temporales,

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo haciendo una consulta dinámica en inglés dynamic query. Puede ser construyendo tu consulta como un string y luego ejecutándola.

En el siguiente enlace podrás encontrar mas información acerca de [dynamic query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).